# FontFactory (lowagie), Java, getting UnsupportedEncodingException when trying to use UniJIS-UCS2-H (for Japanese)

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, fonts, itext

I am using `com.lowagie.text.FontFactory` in generating a PDF file and am trying to use a custom font, KozMinPro-Regular, which provides support for Japanese characters, as we have a need to support this. I have found examples from searching that show how to do this similar to how I am doing it below and these examples assume that `UniJIS-UCS2-H` encoding is supported but when I try this I am getting the exception below that says this encoding is not supported. I would appreciate if anyone may have any insight into this. Thanks

```
FontFactory.register("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/KozMinPro-Regular.ttf", "JapaneseCompatible");
contentFont = FontFactory.getFont("JapaneseCompatible", "UniJIS-UCS2-H", true, 11, Font.BOLD);
headerFont = FontFactory.getFont("JapaneseCompatible", "UniJIS-UCS2-H", true, 11, Font.BOLD);
```

The exception I get:

```
 Exception: [.ReportPdfView] Exception caught during generation of pdf file. Cause: UniJIS-UCS2-H
ExceptionConverter: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UniJIS-UCS2-H
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:286)
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:954)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactoryImp.getFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactoryImp.getFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.getFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.getFont(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `iTextAsian.jar` . It gives CJK support.

see...

http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/ for earlier versions of iText or

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/ for later version of iText.(extrajars.zip contains iTextAsian.jar)

Comment: It's better to get it from Maven, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-asian, because iText Softare doesn't use SourceForge any more.